# How can I position my content in a grid-like fashion

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I have a bunch of controls for a web app that look like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Banana:       | Number of slices: [dropdown] | Slice thickness: [dropdown]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cucumber:     | Number of slices: [dropdown] | Slice thickness: [dropdown]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to place these in a grid-like layout and I have a feeling *tables* are not the way (even if they would be perfect for my situation). I'm having a hard time figuring how to align the columns so they match in position and length (those pipes (|) are not actually visible, but if they were I would like them to be perfectly aligned (and of course everything in the "cells" are of different lengths)).

Comment: I've run into this issue many times and found twitter bootstrap to be the easiest way. It gives you a grid framework and isn't very hard to learn the basics.

Comment: I'm very curious about the answers to this! You could find popular sites that lay out info in a grid, right click to "view source", and see how they do it. But you'll get a bunch of answers before you could do that, I'm sure! (I personally would use tables, but I've never been a "best practices" guy.)

Comment: A table would be proper, but it can be tricky for responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is tabular input. Each row of the table is an ingredient, and each column is indeed a column (first a label column, then a column for the slices, then the thickness). You absolutely *should* use a `<table>` for this.

However, I'd suggest this small change in layout:

```
Ingredient |   Slices   | Thickness
------------------------------------
Banana     | [dropdown] | [dropdown]
------------------------------------
Cucumber   | [dropdown] | [dropdown]
```

Just makes it even more table-like that way ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that tables are a good way to go.  However, if you don't want to use them, you could do something like this:

```
<div id="row">
    <div style="width:10%;left:0">fruit name</div>
    <div style="width:15%;left:10%">slices</div>
    ...
</div>
```

You'll need to play around with relative/absolute positioning between the rows and the sub-items in the rows.  I think you'll want to wrap it all inside of an outer row div to ensure the heights line up.

Comment: But whyyyyyy? It's such a massive headache, so give me a good reason why it's worthwhile...?

Comment: I think it can be more flexible and easier to modify without having to tear everything down and start over.  I agree that it can be cumbersome to learn, but once you get the hang of doing it like this it's not that big of a deal.  Also, they said they didn't want to use tables, and this is how I'd do it without tables.

Comment: What I still don't really understand, in general, is why people will go to so much trouble to basically "re-invent" `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` using only the meaningless `<div>` element...

Comment: Throughout the years I had plenty of people giving me the evil eye for suggesting/using tables. (I don't know what their use case is right now, I just heard they should not be touched.)

Comment: I think it just comes down to personal preference.  Each approach has its strengths and weaknesses.  I'm currently on a project built entirely with divs.  It's built like that because the project lead didn't like tables.  It could have been built with tables too.

Comment: I guess maybe if you were going to be doing a lot of work with divs already, it might make sense to just go all the way, rather than blending the two.